# i20 2011 MAGNA Door Lock Issues?

Tags: hyundai, locks, door, central-locking, i20

Friends! Please cross-check in your car too i20 2011 Magna 1.2 Petrol.
In my car i20 2011 Magna, in point 5, doors are still LOCKED when switch is released fully.
However, doors are UNLOCK automatically as soon as the switch is pressed again and released.
So these 2 points are normal? Please kindly confirm from your end.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: door not unlock after door is reopened from closed.